# WebView darkens all application resources

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Good day. Faced a problem when WebView starts darkening resource files when it appears. When WebView is inactive then all resources and images will be displayed normal. Moreover, this problem exists exclusively on Android 9. This is a very serious problem that occurs on almost all Android 9 devices. I can't understand why Google allows such problems :(
Below I have presented when it is running (right) and when it is not running (left). Look carefully at the flags of the countries, because when the webview is not running, they look nice and blend in with the background, but when it start the flags become ugly and awful

[image: The application looks like this when the WebView is not running] [image: The application looks like this when the WebView has running]

Comment: So where is the question? What do you want others to do?

Comment: I want to fix the problem that Android is not working properly and darkening my resource files

Answer (score 0):

You can set layerType for WebView to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layerType="software"/>
```

or only for Android 9:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 28) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
}
```

UPD: There is a problem. WebView becomes laggy.